# How to write database to CSV (Android)

Tags: android, csv

I have worked out how to fire an e-mail and fill it with information from a database query, but I would like to instead write this to a CSV file so I can use excel to format (maybe attached to an e-mail if this is at all possible).

Below is my code which creates the text to send to an e-mail:

```
private void exportRedRiskItemsToEmail(){

    recipient = email; 

    subject.append(inspectionRef).append(" - Locators Rack Inspection Report (Red Risk Items)");

    message.append("Dear ").append(contactFirstName).append(",\r\n");
    message.append("\r\n");
    message.append("Following todays inspection, below is a list of locations which are noted as Red Risk:\r\n");

    final Cursor areasCursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchAllAreasForInspection(inspectionId);
    if(areasCursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            areaId = areasCursor.getLong(areasCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.AREA_ID));
            areaNumber = RMUtilities.notEmpty(areasCursor.getString(areasCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.AREA_NUMBER)), "number unknown"); 
            areaRef = RMUtilities.notEmpty(areasCursor.getString(areasCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.AREA_REF)), ""); 

            if (areaRef != ""){
                areaRef = " (" + areaRef + ")";
            }
            message.append("______________________________________________________").append("\r\n");
            message.append("\r\n");
            message.append("Area ").append(areaNumber).append(areaRef).append("\r\n");
            message.append("\r\n");

        } 
        while (areasCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    areasCursor.close();
    message.append("______________________________________________________").append("\r\n");
    message.append("\r\n");
    message.append("Please fully off-load above locations (for uprights, please off-load bays either side). \r\n");
    message.append("\r\n");
    message.append("We will follow up with our full report and quotation for repairs shortly. \r\n");
    message.append("\r\n");
    message.append("In the meantime, if you have any queries, please give me a call on 07970 088845. \r\n");
    message.append("\r\n");
    message.append("Kind regards, \r\n");
    message.append("\r\n");
    message.append(inspector).append("\r\n");

    sendEmail(recipient, subject.toString(), message.toString());
}
```

Here is the code which fires the e-mail:

```
private void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String message) { 
    try { 
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
//      emailIntent.setType("high/priority"); //This didn't work - any way to do this though!?
        if (recipient != null)      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient}); 
        if (subject != null)        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
        if (message != null)            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")); 

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
        // cannot send email for some reason 
    } 
}
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  You can just identify the fields of interest and concatenate them with a ',' delimiter for each line.  Was there something specific that was giving you a problem?

Comment: Hi there, well it was the process of exporting to CSV I am a bit unsure about. I just want to get the information out of the database so I can import it into Excel (instead of just outputting text to an e-mail like I am at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [OpenCSV](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/&ei=k37TUP-rMor28wSalIDgAw&usg=AFQjCNG3Pwd9EIuel-nctmq8gWiGjBKHgA&sig2=3ocUVlioIZupleRYoDFgnQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU) library.  It is free, open source, and easy to use.  It does not support directly dumping from SQLite DBs, but it should be pretty straight forward to write the neccessary code to implement this.  OpenCSV does support writing Lists of objects to CSV, so if you can get your data out of the sqlite DB into a List you will be good to go.

Also [here is a post](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/csv/open-csv/bean-to-csv.html) on the topic.

OpenCSV will write to a file as well.  This file then can be attached to an email, or used however you wish(uploaded to google drive, transfered to computer via usb,etc.)

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"));
 // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
 writer.write(entries);
 writer.close();
```

This is just a snippet and I'm working from memory write now so it may be a bit off.  You may also lookup writing files in android.  You can either store this on the external memory or in your application memory.  If you want to access the file from outside your app you will need to place it in external memory.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject line"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body of email"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("yourfile.csv"))); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"); 

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Email:"));
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that looks interesting.  It just takes each string and encases it in "" with commas between.  I suppose I could just alter my code to this myself, but (and this may sound stupid but I am a newbie to all this) would it be better to export to e-mail then copy and paste into notepad doc (to then import into Excel) or is there a simple way of writing directly to text file (if there is there maybe a way of saving this to the e-mail?).  Thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: OpenCsv can be used to write to file.  You may want to read up on using filewriter in android.  It is pretty easy.  Attaching a file to an email can be done with the intent as shown with the code above.

Comment: Thanks again - however, "import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;" didn't work for me, so not sure where you link to this code?

Comment: @Scamparelli You must include the opencsv jar file in your project.  This is usually in the libs directory  of your project.  You must also  include it in your build path.  If you are using eclipse right click on you project and then go to "configure build path".  Then add the jar to the "libraries" tab.